# Can a Filipino with a US C1 visa go to Canada?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, filipino-citizens

I am from the Philippines and I have a C1 US visa. Is that possible for me to visit Canada for a week?

Answer (score 2):

No you need a visa to visit Canada. Only lawful US permanent residents with an alien registration card (Green Card) can visit Canada visa free, no other US visas or statuses are exempt for Filipino citizens.

You can use [this tool](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-tool.asp) for more information from Government of Canada's website

Comment: "Only lawful US permanent residents or people with an alien registration card (Green Card) can visit Canada visa free". That's wildly incorrect. There are quite a few countries get visa-free entry in Canada...

Comment: @dda "no other US visas are exempt" relates to their question

Comment: @dda added extra so its not misconstrued

Comment: The groups "lawful US permanent residents" and "people with an alien registration card (Green Card)" are the same, if you ignore those who have lost their green cards.

Comment: @phoog I thought that too, but its what Canada's website came back with

Comment: @BritishSam the question on the page you linked to says "Are you a lawful permanent resident of the U.S. and have an alien registration card (Green Card)?".  Note *and,* not *or.*  (Having a valid green card implies LPR status, of course, so I suspect the wording is a belt-and-suspenders approach to getting the point across.)